# Create a DNN 7module with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, dotnetnuke, sharepoint-apps

I want to know if there are any projects that use DNN 7 to interact with SharePoint 2013. The SharePoint 2013 is a Provider hosted. For the setup, DNN would be installed on the same server as the App server and SharePoint 2013 on a separate server.  Normally, I would create a SharePoint app that would be installed on the App server. I want to do the same using DNN as the framework with the module as the SharePoint App. Is this possible? I would assume so since SP2013 uses client model. Should I create the SharePoint App project and included it in my DNN project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed SharePoint apps in DotNetNuke by making use of a html module that embeds your app in an iframe element. But since your apps can be hosted on any web hosting stack, you can even probably create a DotNetNuke module that is a Sharepoint app.

You will have to register your app with Azure ACS and with the App Management Service of the SharePoint farm or SharePoint Online tenancy, to be able to establish communication.

Then, to access Sharepoint, you will have to pass an access token in each HTTP request that you can obtain from Microsoft Azure Access Control Service.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790707.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll checkout the link you provided and come back with any additional comments/questions. Thks.

Comment: Sorry I haven't had the chance to test this out since I've been pull to other projects and this was more a proof-of-concept project.